# How to write a CompletableFuture supplyAsync (called in for loop) in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, for-loop, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a for loop to initiate a request based on the incrementation of for loop.

```
List<String> listModel = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    String resp = initiateRequest(i);
    listModel.add(resp);
}

public String initiateRequest(int i)
{
   String url = String.format("http://api.github.com/"+i);
   String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url);
   return response;
}
```

Want to convert this to CompletableFuture Async.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) for iterations and then use [CompletableFuture.supplyAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) for asynchronous request

And use [CompletableFuture.allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) to wait until all future objects get completed

```
 CompletableFuture<String>[] futures = IntStream.range(0,5).mapToObj(i->CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->this.initiateRequest(i)))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::<String>new);

    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
```

On side note `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` uses fork join pool by default and it has some limitation on thread it spin